# Interface Class Confussion

Tags: java, android, javafx

In interface the method does not contain implementation.
so why ActionListener interface provide all the facility of Action, and the method in ActionListener method does not have implementation.
so how it provide functionality of method. like setOnClickListener etc.
i am so confused.please help me

Comment: You need to [override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces define functionality that classes should provide. For example, the `Runnable` interface has one method, `run()`, and any class that implements `Runnable` should have a method in it called `run()`. The same applies to `ActionListener`.

I am not familiar with this interface in particular, but I will use an example from JavaFX, a Java GUI library.

The `Button` class has a method `setOnAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler)`, that sets the action that happens when that button is pressed. `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` is an interface, and server a similar purpose to `ActionListener`. It has one method: `void handle(ActionEvent event);`

My job as the programmer is to provide a class that implements `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`, so that the button knows what method to call when it is pressed. I can do this by:

- Creating a new class in a separate .java file, implementing the interface, and overriding `handle()`
- Creating an anonymous inner class, and override the method there.
- Using a lambda/method reference (Java 8), which is treated as an anonymous inner class by the compiler

By requiring a class which implements `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`, the button knows that there will be a `handle(ActionEvent event)` method available to be called. That is all the interface does. It is simply a promise that a particular method/methods will exist. If you fail to keep this promise (i.e. you don't override the method) the compiler will fail and you will not be able to run your code.

Comment: to say that `That is all the interface does` is a bit unfair, it allows you to do some abstraction/inheritance as well; can use the interface instead of a derived type etc. but this was a solid answer, will upvote, good job for taking time to help someone out :)

Comment: Yes, the answer does sound a bit reductive in hindsight, thanks for the upvote anyways :)